# No qualifying bean of type ... expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, autowired, inject

I am trying  to Inject Repository bean in this project, but keep getting:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.todo.services.TaskReader org.todo.services.AbstractTest.taskReader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.todo.services.TaskReader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.todo.services.TaskReader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

### Project structure:

```
java
  org.todo
   model
     repository 
       TaskRepository
   services
     TaskReader
       impl
         TaskReaderImpl
resources
  config
    applicationContext.cfg.xml
    persistence.cfg.xml
  META-INF 
    persistence.xml
test
 org.todo.services
  AbstractTest
```

### Task Reader:

```
    public interface TaskReader {
    TaskItem findOne(long id);

    List<TaskItem> findByOwner(ToDoUser toDoUser);

    List<TaskItem> findAll();
}
```

### Task Reader Implementation:

```
@Service

@Transactional(readOnly = true)

public class TaskReaderImpl implements TaskReader {

    @Resource
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;
    @Inject
    private UserReader userReader;
...
```

### TaskRepository:

```
    @Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Long> {

    @Query("select t from tasks t where t.owner = :user order by t.done, t.startedDate")
    List<Task> findAllByOwner(@Param("user") User user);

    @Query("select t from tasks t order by t.done, t.startedDate")
    List<Task> findAll();

    @Query("delete from tasks t where t.owner= :user")
    void deleteAllByOwner(@Param("user") User user);
}
```

I am using `TaskReader` in some tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:config/applicationContext.cfg.xml")
public class AbstractTest {
    @Inject
    private TaskReader taskReader;
    @Inject
    private TaskWriter taskWriter;
    @Inject
    private UserWriter userWriter;
    @Inject
    private UserReader userReader;
```

### applicationContext.cfg.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <!--<context:annotation-config/>-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <import resource="persistence.cfg.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.todo.controller"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.todo.utils"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.todo.services"/>

    <bean id="conversionService"
          class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### persistence.cfg.xml:

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.todo.model.repository"/>

    <bean id="jpaVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="H2"/>
    </bean>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <!-- Drives transactions using local JPA APIs -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="rollbackOnCommitFailure" value="true"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="to-do-list"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendor"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Now I am given Error of `autowired` bean, but I couldn`t to find this error!

### Full stackTrace:

> Listener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.todo.services.TaskReader org.todo.services.AbstractTest.taskReader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.todo.services.TaskReader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>       ... 24 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.todo.services.TaskReader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
>       ... 26 more
>   11:55:10,850 DEBUG ProfileValueUtils:68 - Retrieved @PtProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.todo.services.TaskReader org.todo.services.AbstractTest.taskReader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.todo.services.TaskReader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>       ... 24 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.todo.services.TaskReader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
>       ... 26 more
>   11:55:10,894 DEBUG ProfileValueUtils:68 - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [org.todo.services.TaskServicesTest]
>   11:55:10,895 DEBUG ProfileValueUtils:80 - Retrieved Profile11:55:11,135 TRACE TestContextManager:427 - afterTestClass(): class [class org.todo.services.TaskServicesTest]
>   11:55:11,137 DEBUG DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:138 - After test class: context [[TestContext@1974736 testClass = TaskServicesTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@c44deb testClass = TaskServicesTest, locations = '{classpath*:config/applicationContext.cfg.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]], dirtiesContext [false].
>   11:55:11,155  INFO GenericApplicationContext:1042 - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@c1d5a3: startup date [Mon Jan 27 11:55:10 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
>   11:55:11,156 TRACE GenericApplicationContext:332 - Publishing event in org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@c1d5a3: org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@c1d5a3: startup date [Mon Jan 27 11:55:10 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy]
>   11:55:11,158 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
>   11:55:11,159  INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory:444 - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7c49e3: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55631', transport: 'socket'

**project source**: [github](http://github.com/Aventes/todo).

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace. It looks like you only posted a snippet. Judging from your configuration file headers you are mixing several versions of schema's (2.5, 3.0, 3.2) I suggest moving them all to the version-less version this ensures the usage of the most recent version.

Comment: I had added to the post.

Comment: Is your `resources` directory on your classpath?

Comment: Try `classpath:` instead of `classpath*:`. Can you add the concrete testcase you are using instead of only the abstract one.

Comment: For tests running i using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:config/applicationContext.cfg.xml")`. Please, look this part of the project. https://github.com/Aventes/todo. This is unworking part

Comment: Can you try to move the @Repository annotation to the implementation class and see if that works?

Comment: Ok. I doing that: `public interface TaskRepository{ ...methods ...}` implementation to: `public class TaskRepositoryImpl implements TaskRepository{ ...implemants methods.... }`.  And, as result the same error  _NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.todo.model.repository.TaskRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=taskRepository), @javax.inject.Inject()}_